# Creat a random group variable in long format

Tags: r, random

Im working in R with a long format dataset. I have on variable (City) and every row is an indivudal with age, sex and som more info. I now want to creat a variable which is either 0 or 1 and i want the distibution of 0 and 1 to be close to 50/50 distibution.

My data looks similar to this. The length of the city variable is not necessary the same length.

```
   Sample    City    Age   Sex
   1        City_a   15     M
   2        City_a   27     F
   3        City_a   25     M
   4        City_b   20     M
```

And i want to get something like :

```
   Sample    City    Age   Sex   Random_g
   1        City_a   15     M      0 
   2        City_a   27     F      0
   3        City_a   25     M      1
   4        City_b   20     M      1
```

I started by doing following but didn't work due to my setting size to 1 and I dont know what else to set it to.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
group_by(City) %>% 
mutate(Random_g =sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE,size=1))
```

Tried following which works but then the distribution of 0/1 can be anything:

```
df %>% 
rowwise() %>% 
mutate(Random_g =sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE,size=1))
```

Edit: So I noticed that how i wrote it may be a bit confusing. Some of the City can have 300 samples in it ( and in that case I would like to have 150 0 and 150 1) and some have 1000 in them.

Edit2: solved it using Jimbou example:

```
  df%>%
  group_by(City) %>% 
  mutate(Rand_g=sample(c(0,1),length(Age), replace=TRUE, prob = c(0.5,0.5)))
```

Comment: `round(runif(100),0)` gives you 100 zeros and ones close to 50/50

Comment: If you are not set on `dplyr`, use base R as follows: `df$Random_g <- rbinom(nrow(df), 1, .5)`.

Comment: This `sample(c(0,1),100, replace=TRUE, prob = c(0.5,0.5))`

Comment: `ifelse(sample(1:100) < 51, 1, 0))` gives you exactly 50 zeroes and 50 ones

Answer (score 0):

My comment more generalized:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(randomgroup = ifelse(sample(1:n(), n()) <= n() / 2, 1, 0))
```

This gives you an equal amount of 1's and 0's per cyl, and in case you have an uneven number of rows in a cyl, it will have an extra 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df%>%
  mutate(Rand_g=sample(0:1, n(), replace=TRUE, prob = c(0.5,0.5)))
```

The `group_by(City) %>%` is not necessary as the  [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) says that in both groups the numbers converges to 50%. Or so... (I'm not a statistician)